# Jenkins ver 1.647 generates and displays non-coloured Selenium HTML report

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

[image]

Test suite results in black and white as against the regular green for pass and red for fails

Answer (score 0):

Thats easy to debug.  Just run Chrome and view the report while you have the Chrome network traffic debugger enabled.  When it fails to download a style sheet, you'll see an error and then you will know the reason why the page doesn't completely render correctly.